# How to perform a function in Vue3 only once when it is loaded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, lifecycle, vue-composition-api

Inside the project, I used fake api, and in a component with setup, before the component is mounted, I get it and display it.
But the problem is that I make a series of changes on the same page on the captured apis, but when I render another page and go back to the previous page that has the api, this time because it is mounted, it executes the setup and the tasks I did on that page. They disappear. What can I do to make it run only when it is first loaded and not to run that code when it is mounted???

```
setup(){
    const store = useStore();
    
    
    async function getApi(){
            await store.dispatch('task/getTasks')    
          }
    getApi()

    const tasks = computed(()=> store.state['task'].tasks)
    

    return{tasks}
  }
```

Comment: `setup` is done once, `mounted` is done everytime the component is mounted. Simple solution would be to move all the logic from `mounted` to `setup` (or the opposite). Not sure to fully understand the issue here.

Comment: Can you post the code of all the relevant components?

Comment: @mohammadzohdi flagged. Please post it here rather than via phone.